# How to printing text to screen in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I open a label to print text on the screen, I write what I want, but it does not appear on the screen when I run it.[image: Here it is code][image: Here it is emulator]

I recreated the page but my problem still persists I don't understand how to do it I was waiting for it to work when I deleted the page and rebuilt it

Comment: please put the codes as text not screenshot

Comment: I would but the character limit is reached if i delete the original text my question will deleted

Comment: Try setting the text color to black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I couldn't reproduce this problem.

And just as Andrew said, you can try to set the text color of your label to black:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormApp1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="lbls"  Text="Start developing now"  TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```